# InnerHTML with onclick= not executing associated JS functions

Tags: javascript

I have a table, that when being edited replaces the cell with an input field using the JS below.

```
account.innerHTML="<input type='text'  id='account_text"+no+"' value='"+account_data+"' class='dropbutton2' onclick='dropdownFunction2(); options2()' onkeyup='filterFunction2()'> <div id='myDropdown2' class='dropdown-content2'></div>";
```

When the input field is clicked I want the dropdown div to be shown using this JS:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function dropdownFunction2 (){
  document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
  document.getElementById('myDropdown2').innerHTML = '';
}
//Searchable dropdown
function filterFunction2(){
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbutton2");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown2");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
//Get the dropdown content
function options2 (){
  document.querySelectorAll(".accname").forEach(element => {
    let dropdown = document.querySelector("#myDropdown2");
    let options = document.querySelectorAll("#myDropdown2 > a").length;
    dropdown.innerHTML = dropdown.innerHTML + '<a id="accselectedit' + (options + 1) + '" onclick="selectAccountedit(\'' + element.innerText + '\')"> ' + element.innerText + ' </a>'
  });
}
//if dropdown is visible, on off click hide



//Fill selected account as input
function selectAccountedit(value) {
  input = document.querySelectorAll(".dropbutton2");
  input.value = value;
}
```

Unfortunately none of the functions (except maybe options2) is triggered. The only way I can get the dropdown to show on click in the input field is by giving .dropdown-content2 display: block via css. But the js function that's supposed to handle visibility is not working.

Any idea why it's not working? Originally I used get elementById instead of query selector but I'm not sure I can use Id in this case.

Comment: Well if the class show being added? Is the class show being overwritten in the CSS?

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: I beilieve the DOM isnt picking your event handlers, instead of writing the event handlers as html attributes, you can use `addEventListener` with appropriate events

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right the event handlers aren't working. I'll try reworking the functions one by one.